# Finding a generating set

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a subspace of $Z^3$, $N=\{(x,y,z)\in Z^3| 2x+3y-5z=0\}$. How to find the generating set for $N$. I tried to solve it for $z$ but then my generating set is not in $Z^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtain the solution for $2x+3y = 5z$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ using [Bezout's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Hover your mouse over the gray area for a complete solution.

> A trivial solution is given by $$(x,y) = (z,z)$$ where $z \in \mathbb{Z}$.
> Hence, all the solutions to $2x+3y = 5z$ is given by $$(x,y,z) = (z+3a,z-2a,z)$$ where $a,z \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So the generating set can be written as {(1,1,1),(3,-2,0)} ?